# How to center layout with material design on generator-gulp-angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm use [generator-gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) with angular-material-design and ui-router

Well, all views load into index.html in element `<div ui-view></div>`

But when I try to  center the element with the directives from material design inside the this element not center

for example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/LsXikk thats what I need...

but this is what I get:
http://plnkr.co/edit/9LzHzE

I hope explain myself clearly

**update:** I can touch de element with ui-view because other views will be loaded inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing the simple thing. Whenever you use `ui-view` to load a view file, you should use `layout-fill` attribute in the 1st container element in that view file. check out this link.
  http://plnkr.co/edit/GvOWET  If you have any trouble let me know.

Comment: Nice! thank you very much! It's work!
I fighting with this two days hahaha
Thanks again
Can you let me more information for material design for beginners? and can you tell me why this thing work?

Comment: No problem at all. I think it's documentation is the best place to learn. `layout-fill` forces the layout element to fill its parent container. This is what the offical doc says. check out more cool things on https://material.angularjs.org/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You were just missing some of the attributes on the `div` with the `ui-view` directive:

`<div layout="row" flex layout-align="center center">`

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/U47odgrKHi5bxQ7VTWWY)

Comment: but I can touch de element with ui-view because other views will be loaded inside